# AWS images block

Tags: image, exif, http-status-code-403, web-application-firewall

I'm working on an AWS Ubuntu Server protected by the WAF Shield and I'm seeing a strange (at least I think) behaviour.

When an image is uploaded to my system, some of them are being denied some not.
All the images are validated and the upload of some of them returns an error 403 (Forbidden). If I open the same image in any image editor and just save it as a new file (of the same type etc..), this second file is uploaded normally.

This doesn't have a pattern of size, type or any detail of the image. The best guess that we have is the EXIF present (or not) inside the image.

Did anyone had problems like this?

Comment: Test your theory using `jhead` or **ImageMagick**'s `identify -verbose someImage.jpg`

Comment: Hi Mark, checking the files I saw that some values have changed between them but these caught my attention:  - Resolution (not present vs 72x72) - Print size (not present vs 3.611x2.69) - Units (undefined x PixesPerInch) and Interface (None x JPEG) _in all examples the blocked image has the first value_

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. You can remove the EXIF data with `mogrify -strip filename.jpg` then the image uploads